# Can InDesign import .xlsm files?

Tags: adobe-indesign, import, microsoft-excel

I need to import an .xlsm file (as a linked file) into InDesign, but couldn't select it in the Import Dialogue. There, I would need to extract only individual cells. Tried making several versions of the .xlsm file, plus new ones, none of which could be imported.

Is it because InDesign generally does not support .xlsm files or could there be a specific problem? I already googled this and didn't find anything that adressed the issue...

Many thanks if somebody has info about this!

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot.

From my experience you will need to covert it to XML.  If I were you I would script a solution or you can use many conversion tools online to achieve this.  After converting to XML, test the XML output before importing it into InDesign.

Comment: @darth-vader Thanks! Good to know there's a definite answer :)